# C++ Iterate Over All Generics At Once

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers

The following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class type>
struct A {
    type i;
    A(type j){
        i = j;
    }
};

template<class type>
std::vector<A<type>*> ve;

int main(int argc, char** args){
    ve<int>.push_back(new A<int>(1));
    ve<int>.push_back(new A<int>(2));
    ve<char>.push_back(new A<char>('a'));
    ve<char>.push_back(new A<char>('b'));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ve<int>.size(); i++)
        std::cout << ve<int>[i]->i << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ve<char>.size(); i++)
        std::cout << ve<char>[i]->i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
1
2
a
b
```

**How can I reproduce the same output, but with only one for loop?**
Yes I understand the preprocessor made two different vectors here.
Show me how to combine them or show me a generic for loop.

Comment: Are you trying to learn C++ coming from a Java background, by any chance?

Comment: I have programmed in Java before, but no templates or interfaces.

Comment: You should forget everything you know about Java, if your intent is to learn C++. C++ is not Java, and despite similar syntax, C++ works in fundamentally different ways. There's nothing in the code above that -- for example -- requires anything to be `new`ed. In C++, for example, objects are ***not*** created by the `new` keyword. The `new` keyboard is something entirely different. You've just created a bunch of memory leaks, above. It's better to spend some time learning C++ fundamentals, before trying to learn advanced concepts like templates, otherwise this will only confuse you.

Comment: Keep in mind this example is for simplicity's sake. I know the difference between stack and heap, and how to use smart pointers. All of the memory here is automatically released upon termination of the program. In my real code the A structure is much larger and pointers are needed.

Comment: _"All of the memory here is automatically released upon termination of the program"_ No, you leaked it all.

Comment: "Yes I understand the preprocessor made two different vectors here." It did not. The preprocessor is _not_ involved in template initialization (it does not understand templates at all).

Comment: The above comments should hopefully emphasize that C++ is radically different than you think it is. If your intent is truly to understand and thoroughly learn C++, you're wasting your time trying to reverse-engineer how C++ works based on what you know about Java. If your intent is to implement a vector of polymorphic objects, this is not how this gets done in C++, by using templates. It's your choice whether you want to learn C++ thoroughly, starting with fundamental concepts, or by trial and error, trying this syntax or that one, until the compiler stops complaining, and hope for the best.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're claiming the OS will not reclaim that memory when the exe terminates?

Comment: "*How can I reproduce the same output, but with only one for loop?*"- you can't. You can certainly run a single loop to access both vectors at the same time, but to OUTPUT the values in the order you showed, you would have to cache the values to a temp list and then run a second loop to sort/output *that* list in the desired order.

Comment: @PhilM No, but it's not "released" per se. Add a few destructors and you have a problem. Always free your memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct B {
    virtual void memberOut(){}
};

template<class type>
struct A : B{
    type i;
    A(type j):B(){
        i = j;
    }
    void memberOut(){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<B*> ve;

int main(int argc, char** args){
    ve.push_back(new A<int>(1));
    ve.push_back(new A<int>(2));
    ve.push_back(new A<char>('a'));
    ve.push_back(new A<char>('b'));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ve.size(); i++)
        ve[i]->memberOut();
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:
Either keep it as two containers, or make virtual functions. Both have their uses.
Using a template on a variable just makes two variables.
You can also save another vector of type_index and use typeid to remember what pointer type a void pointer is later on, but that's just a sloppier version of virtual functions. Example:

```
std::vector<void*> values
std::vector<std::type_index> types
if(types[i]==typeid(A<int>*))
```

Side Notes:
Try not to get off-base when writing comments.
The objective of comments is to get the question answered, not debate.